# How to let espresso wait for Splash Screen to finish and then start the tests

Tags: android, android-espresso

Hello i have to write a test for my Activity but before this `Activity` a `SplashActivity` has to run first for 2500ms.

My test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class GuestActivityTest{

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<GuestActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<GuestActivity>(GuestActivity.class, true, false){
        @Override
        protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
            super.afterActivityLaunched();
        }
    };



    @Test
    public void goToMenuActivity() {
        onView(withId(R.id.button_log_in)).perform(typeText("Works"));
        onView(withId(R.id.menu_btn)).perform(click());
    }
}
```

The test crashes every time because the initialization in the `SplashActivity` has not been performed. How to let espresso know that the `Activity` has already been loaded or wait for the `SplashActivity` to be finished first?

Answer (score 7):

As Shurov suggested I thinkt that the way to go is to use Espresso idling resources. To do this first add the dependency

```
implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.3.0"
```

Then add this class to your project

```
object EspressoIdlingResource {

    private val CLASS_NAME = "EspressoIdlingResource"

    private const val RESOURCE = "GLOBAL"

   @JvmField val countingIdlingResource = CountingIdlingResource(RESOURCE)

   fun increment() {
        countingIdlingResource.increment()
   }

   fun decrement() {
      if (!countingIdlingResource.isIdleNow) {
         countingIdlingResource.decrement()
      }
   }
}
```

Once that is done add EspressoIdlingResource.increment() when you start up your splash Activity and EspressoIdlingResource.decreasment() when you navigate away from it.

Then add this to your test class.

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource)
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource)
}
```

After this your test should automatically wait for your SplashActivity o finish.

Here is Googles page about the topic https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource.

Answer (score 2):

maybe have a delay action at the beginning of the test case

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(waitFor(5000));
```

the waitFor function:

```
public static ViewAction waitFor(long delay) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return ViewMatchers.isRoot();
        }

        @Override public String getDescription() {
            return "wait for " + delay + "milliseconds";
        }

        @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(delay);
        }
    };
}
```

Tried and tested (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at it yet, so can't suggest ready code, but try looking for `Idling Resource` that will wait for splash screen end

Answer (score -1):

Create an activity that can combine the role of splashScreen and the role of the activity

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

Sleep the thread to match the execution delay of the app.

```
@Test
public void goToMenuActivity() {
    try {
    Thread.sleep(60000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    onView(withId(R.id.button_log_in)).perform(typeText("Works"));
    onView(withId(R.id.menu_btn)).perform(click());
}
```

Comment: It isn't so beautiful, but it works without tons of code.